# Google Sheets: Return cell value in a range/array based on multiple criteria (including comparison of value between two numbers)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

Would really appreciate some help with this issue which I've been struggling with for a while. I believe the answer is somewhere in Match, Index, Indirect, ArrayFormula but I'm struggling to find it.

So my main goal is to get the **cost of a product** based on 3 (technically two) evaluations. The input that I have available is the *Tier* and the *weight*.

| Example | Tier | Weight kg | Prod Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Example 1 | SPC | 0.65 | ? |
| Example 2 | STE | 0.15 | ? |

The reference table from which the product cost will be derived is below:

| Row | Tier | Min Wt(kg) | Max Wt (kg) | Prod Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SME | 0.00 | 0.10 | 4.0 |
| 2 | STE | 0.00 | 0.10 | 4.5 |
| 3 | STE | 0.10 | 0.25 | 4.7 |
| 4 | STE | 0.25 | 0.50 | 5.0 |
| 5 | LE | 0.00 | 1.00 | 5.5 |
| 6 | SPC | 0.00 | 0.25 | 5.7 |
| 7 | SPC | 0.25 | 0.50 | 6.0 |
| 8 | SPC | 0.50 | 1.00 | 6.5 |
| 9 | SPC | 1.00 | 1.50 | 7.0 |

In order to get the product cost I need to evaluate the *tier* and then the evaluate which range of min and max weight the product weight falls into (for that tier).

So taking example 1, the tier is SPC which makes *Row 6 to 9* valid. Then the weight is 0.65 which is between the min and max weight values of 0.5kg and 1.0kg in *row 8*. Therefore the product cost is 6.5.

Kindly note that both criteria are important as the weight ranges overlap between tiers.

Any help on how to evaluate this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: how many tier variation you got in your real dataset?

Comment: There are 5. Total rows around 45. Not much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(F2:F, {UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"")), 
 SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A))*10000}, 2, 0)+G2:G, {
 VLOOKUP(A2:A, {UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"")), 
 SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A))*10000}, 2, 0)+B2:B, D2:D}, 2, 1)))
```

[image]

---

how it works:

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExG2OfCbziCT5IxiQx-affc6UvdafiUFq4W6I5aifRI/copy)

Comment: Wow first of all thank you for the lightning fast response. what an amazing community. Secondly the formula absolutely works! My only issue is that when I copy paste it, it give me an error that the lower cell will be over written. so it displays the answer one row below. Apologies I'm a bit of a noob on this so a bit of unpacking the formula would really help. So Filter, MOD and Sequence are all new to me. I've looked at the functions and trying to make sense of it. For now I'd really like to understand where the weight min max is being evaluated :S.

Comment: @AdnanM its ARRAYFORMULA which means it auto-calculates for all rows, which means you need to clear the whole your column and use this in first row where your dataset begins. you can drop the max column. it uses only MIN column and formula looks for exact match or higher approximation. happy to explain the whole formula if you wish...

Comment: @AdnanM see basics: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/123730/186471

Comment: honestly if you could explain the whole formula I would be highly indebted to you. I've been trying to replicate it part by part but I'm unable to grasp the logic. Thanks so much in advance for help.

Comment: Dear @player0. This is so kind of you. What a great logic and fantastic step by step instruction! I was going in a completely different path and this makes so much more sense. Thanks a million for all your support. And sorry for the delay in responding was 1 am at my end so couldn’t keep eyes open.